# How to concatenate cells conditionally

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with two columns.

The first column has a number or reoccurring reference like xyz. 
The second column has a list of names.

I would like to program a formula to concatenate all names in column 2, that have 'xyz' in column 1.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your question is not clear. The screenshot seems to be unrelated to your question. Post a screenshot of your INPUT data and mock up the desired output manually. Edit your question to do that. Do NOT put that into a comment. Post a comment to alert the people who are following this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to concatenate Name Column where column Countif are not blank, like this:

```
=textjoin(",",false,filter(B2:B,A2:A<>""))
```

or if you next just want to get data Name where column Countif are not blank, do like this:

```
= filter(B2:B,A2:A<>"")
```